# Bigquery - parametrize tables and columns in a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery, prepared-statement, table-functions

Consider an enterprise that captures sensor data for different production facilities. per facility, we create an aggregation query that averages the values to 5min timeslots. This query  exists out of a long list of with-clauses and writes data to a table (called aggregation_table).

Now my problem: currently we have n queries running that exactly run the same logic, the only thing that differs are table names (and sometimes column names but let's ignore that for now).

Instead of managing n different scripts that are basically the same, I would like to put it in a stored procedure that is able to work like this:

CALL aggregation_query(facility_name) -> resolve the different tables for that facility and then use them in the different with clauses

On top of that, instead of having this long set of clauses that give me the end-result, I would like to chunk them up in logical blocks that are parametrizable, So for example, if I call the aforementioned stored_procedure for facility A, I want to be able to pass / use this table name in these different functions, where the output can be re-used in the next statement (like you would do with with clauses).

Another argument of why I want to chunk this up in re-usable blocks is because we have many "derivatives" on this aggregation query, for example to manage historical data, to correct data or to have the sensor data on another aggregation level. As these become overly complex, it is much easier to manage them without having to copy paste and adjust these every time.

In the current set-up, it could be useful to know that I am only entitled to use plain BigQuery, As my team is not allowed to access the CI/CD / scheduling and repository. (meaning that I cannot solve the issue by having CI/CD that deploys the n different versions of the procedure and functions)

So in the end, I would like to end up with something like this using only bigquery:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
  `aggregation_function`()
BEGIN
DECLARE
  tablename STRING;
DECLARE
  active_table_name STRING; ##get list OF tables CREATE TEMP TABLE tableNames AS
SELECT
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name
FROM
  `catalog.schema.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
WHERE
  table_name = tablename;
WHILE
  (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
    tableNames) >= 1 DO ##build dataset + TABLE name
SET
  active_table_name = CONCAT('`',table_catalog,'.',table_schema,'.' ,table_name,'`'); ##use concat TO build string AND execute
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
INSERT INTO
  `aggregation_table_for_facility` (timeslot, sensor_name, AVG_VALUE )
WITH
  STEP_1 AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    my_table_function_step_1(active_table_name,
      parameter1,
      parameter2) ),
  STEP_2 AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    my_table_function_step_2(STEP_1,
      parameter1,
      parameter2) )
  SELECT * FROM STEP_2
  '''
USING active_table_name as active_table_name;
DELETE
FROM
  tableNames
WHERE
  table_name = tablename;
END WHILE
  ;
END
  ;
```

I was hoping someone could make a snippet on how I can do this in Standard SQL / Bigquery, so basically:

- stored procedure that takes in a string variable and is able to use that as a table (partly solved in the approach above, but not sure if there are better ways)
- (table) function that is able to take this table_name parameter as well and return back a table that can be used in the next with clause (or alternatively writes to a temp table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below code snippets should provide you with some insights when dealing with procedures, inserts and execute immediate statements.

Here I'm creating a procedure which will insert values into a table that exists on the information schema. Also, as a value I want to return I use `OUT` *active_table_name* to return the value I assigned inside the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `project-id.dataset`.custom_function(tablename STRING,OUT active_table_name STRING)
BEGIN
 
DECLARE query STRING; 

SET active_table_name= (SELECT CONCAT('`',table_catalog,'.',table_schema,'.' ,table_name,'`')
                        FROM `project-id.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
                        WHERE table_name = tablename);

#multine query can be handled by using ''' or """ 
Set query = 
'''
insert into %s (string_field_0,string_field_1,string_field_2,string_field_3,string_field_4,int64_field_5)
with custom_query as (
   select string_field_0,string_field_2,'169 BestCity',string_field_3,string_field_4,55677 from %s limit 1
)
select * from custom_query;
''';

# querys must perform operations and must be the last thing to perform
# pass parameters using format 
execute immediate (format(query,active_table_name,active_table_name));

END
```

You can also use a loop to iterate trough records from a working table so it will execute the procedure and also be able to get the value from the procedure to use somewhere else.ie:*A second procedure to perform a delete operation*.

```
DECLARE tablename STRING; 
DECLARE out_value STRING; 

FOR record IN
  (SELECT tablename from `my-project-id.dataset.table`)
DO 
  SET tablename = record.tablename;
  LOOP
    call `project-id.dataset`.custom_function(tablename,out_value);
    select out_value;
  END LOOP; 
END FOR;
```

To recap, there are some restrictions such as the possibility to call procedures inside a execute immediate or to use execute immediate inside an execute immediate, to count a few. I think these snippets should help you dealing with your current situation.

For this sample I use the following documentation:

- [Data Manipulation Language](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax)
- [Dealing with outputs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-output)
- [Information Schema Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables)
- [Execute Immediate](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate)
- [For...In](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#for-in)
- [Loops](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#loops)

Comment: Hello Olivier Thierie, have you managed to make it work?